# Error when passing a variable declared as `extern char[]` to a function template in VC++

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, gcc, clang

Consider the following (artificial) example:

```
template <typename T>
void f(const T&) {}

extern char test[];

int main() {
  f(test);
}

char test[] = "";
```

Both GCC and Clang compile it successfully, but Visual C++ gives the following error:

> test.cc(7): error C2664: 'f' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char
>   []' to 'const char (&)[1]' [...vcxproj]
>             Reason: cannot convert from 'char []' to 'const char [1]'
>             There is no context in which this conversion is possible

Why does VC++ gives this error while other compilers accept the code and how to avoid this error?

Comment: To avoid the error, stop using C-style arrays... they don't have proper value semantics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting C++11 8.3.5-8:

> If the type of a parameter includes a type of the form “pointer to array of unknown bound of T” or “reference
>   to array of unknown bound of T,” the program is ill-formed.

At the time that `f(test)` is called, `test` has type `char []`, and `T` is deducted to `char []`. Then f will have the parameter of type `const char(&)[]`, which is not allowed.

So VC++ is right. It might be the compiler's extension or bug if it accepts this.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out this is a [C++ Language Core Language Issue 393](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#393) with the proposed resolution of removing the clause

> If the type of a parameter includes a type of the form “pointer to
>   array of unknown bound of T” or “reference to array of unknown bound
>   of T,” the program is ill-formed.

which is what both GCC and Clang do. The EDG front-end (which is used by Visual C++) developers chose to issue an error in this case despite the term "include a type" being not defined by the standard.